# mysql create index from batch vs. CLI or GUI

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench, etl

I'm trying to index an existing (and populated) table in mysql as part of an ETL script in PHP. I have two index statements (call this `create_index.sql`):

```
create index my_index_1 on my_table (my_col_1);
create fulltext index my_index_2 on my_table (my_col_2 asc, my_col_3 asc);
```

This is automated through PHP, run after population via loading a SQL (text) file and executing it as a batch:

```
$conn = new mysqli('my_host', 'my_user', 'my_pass', 'my_db');
$result = $conn->query(file_get_contents('create_index.sql');
if (false === $result)
    error_log($conn->error);
```

When executed as listed above (via PHP), I get a standard 'You have an error in your SQL syntax' message.

When executed in MySQL Workbench, the two `create index` statements, exactly the same, run without error.

Can someone point me in the direction of what the GUI is doing differently, between statements I assume, that leads to different results for the same statements? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: You would need to split the lines in the file and then execute them one at a time. The query method expects a single sql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute each SQL statement in the file separately. The splitting of the statements could be more elegant, but based on what you show in your question, this should work:

```
$conn = new mysqli('my_host', 'my_user', 'my_pass', 'my_db');
$sql_file_text = file_get_contents('create_index.sql');
$sql = explode(';',$sql_file_text);
foreach($sql as $key => $sql_statement) {
    if($sql_statement != '') {
        $result = $conn->query($sql_statement);
        if (false === $result) {
            error_log($conn->error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Can you point me towards the direction of why? Are there certain kinds of batches that _are_ allowed, or is there a firm one-statement-per-execution limit?

Comment: There is another method to execute multi-statement queries. For query, it is a hard limit. Look up the method in the mysql docs for more info. For the other method, see [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)